# Signed Commit in git2-rs not appearing in repo

Tags: rust, git2-rs

I'm trying to used signed commits with git2 in rust if there is a signkey in the gitconfig, I have found that using a regular commit, everything works fine and automatically is picked up however when i use `commit_signed` it doesn't show up in the repo and it is as if the commit doesn't exist. Is there something i am missing